# Computational neuroscience postdoc prospects given computational neuropsychology Ph.D. research?

Tags: phd, research-process, career-path, computer-science, postdocs

I have been accepted for a Ph.D. in computer science (CS) and funded projects I am applying for are computationally focused whole brain neuroimaging (e.g., MRI, DTI) cognitive neuropsychology research with new experimentally-derived human data. My end goal is to do computational neuroscience at a molecular electrophysiology level using experimentally-derived subject data which my biology, math, and CS background and prior neuro research projects help with (also, would greatly enjoy the positions but end goal strong favorite).

Would doing a Ph.D. with my research in those funded positions (which are more top-down whole brain, as opposed to my bottom-up individual neuron end goal) prohibit me from being a good applicant for postdoc positions in my end goal research area? How much of an extra challenge would this cause compared to doing a Ph.D. directly with research in my end goal?

In general terms: would agreeing to do funded research for a Ph.D. in a related area to the one that is eventually desired allow for getting a postdoc in a position one most wants? Also, what are good ways to do extra work during the degree toward the postdoc wanted?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: @aparente001 Please allow me to add descriptions that help clarify the question and thank you for alerting me to it not being clear. I have added a description in parenthesis to try to help clarification. My question is: if I do a Ph.D. with research in a related but different area to my ultimate goal research, will that still lead to me being a good candidate for a postdoc in research in the ultimate goal area? Are there other things I can say to try to help explain the question better? Thanks!

Comment: @compneurophile Computational neuroscience, even with respect to your "bottom-up individual neuron end goal", is still big enough to make your question too broad. Are you talking about working with "realistic" data-driven models (which involves a lot of mathematics), or analyzing experimental data (which still involves a lot of mathematics, but also potentially machine learning or image processing), or something else. There is also often a fair amount of (software/hardware) engineering required in major projects, e.g. to develop some of the experimental systems.

Comment: @compneurophile That being said, researchers in the field understand the highly multidisciplinary nature of the field, so as long as you have a chance to familiarise yourself in your CS PhD with some of the essential low-level neuroscience knowledge (electrophysiology, neuroanatomy, neuromodulation, etc), you should be okay.

Comment: people commenting must be from other fields, because this really isn't an unclear question. obviously it would be best to study your topic of interest now, rather than bank on getting a post-doc doing what you like 5+ years from now. that said, if you have no choice but to stick with your current lab for the PhD, it certainly is possible to switch to molecular/cellular comp neuro for the post-doc. in fact, i've done just that. i did my PhD doing psychophysics and some modeling in an fMRI lab, and will be starting a post-doc this fall in a comp neurosci lab.

Comment: @101010111100 Thanks for the further explanations. In the position I would work with experimental data on neuroimaging, not “realistic” modeling in the purely theoretical side. I have updated the question’s first paragraph to include that. I want to somewhat avoid being too specific about the work for anonymity reasons. Does that help the question to be clear?

Comment: @dbliss That is encouraging to find that you have done it, well done! Thanks for saying the Q is understandable. In this case, the potential position is the best one available after I have tried my Ph.D. applications. A question I have is how much extra preparation do you view do needed to do to get accepted into the comp neurosci lab.? Also what was your Ph.D. major?

Comment: my PhD is in Neuroscience. i took time in my PhD to teach myself how to do neural modeling at the cellular level, and i am (hopefully) about to publish a paper with such a model in it. i'm sure that experience helped me sell myself to the computational lab for the post-doc. i've also tried to stay up to date with the computational literature most directly related to the questions i'm interested in.

Comment: @dbliss That’s impressive about the paper, best of luck on it! Given that you said you’ve worked in an fMRI lab, how did you find a way to do the paper with cellular modeling? Did you pitch it to the lab or find another way to do it?

Comment: i have a very hands-off advisor, and i used that to go off in a direction pretty different from what other people in my lab are doing. my neural modeling is focused on cognitive questions that other people in my lab are approaching with fMRI. so there is a relationship there. even if your advisor keeps tighter control on you, i'd bet you can connect his work to some kind of computational question that excites you.

Comment: @dbliss Good advice thanks so much! That was savvy to maneuver your way into that. Advisers can range such a lot in terms of allowing certain work, but I too like to believe that if a good evidence-based case is made and it relates to their work, than at least one article can be added in that direction.

Comment: This question should remain open. It is clear that the asker is asking whether expertise in computationally focused whole brain neuroimaging (e.g., MRI, DTI) cognitive neuropsychology can be applied to another, related, area to the extent of doing a postdoc. That's not a question that depends on personal circumstances. That the asker has received useful answers, demonstrates it is a good question.

Comment: ThomasKing Thanks for the support! To @scaaahu MassimoOrtolano aparente001 Buzz user3209815 I have added a statement to describe the question in terms that generalize to other situations, and I trimmed some extra descriptions that was complicating the question. Please tell me if more editing of the post is wanted, thanks!